# Rerun Function When Clicking Anchor Link Received Using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a page transition effect using jQuery and Ajax. Currently what I have is:

```
$(".transitionLink").on("click", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    window.history.pushState(null, null, href);

    $(".transitionLink").removeClass("transitionLink--active");
    $(this).addClass("transitionLink--active");

    $.ajax({
            url: href,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#transition").fadeOut(250, function () {


                    var newPage = $(data).find('#transition').html();


                    $("#transition").html(newPage);


                    $("#transition").fadeIn(250);

                });



            }
    });

});
```

So what this is doing is whenever an anchor tag with the class of `transitionLink` is clicked it will grab the href attribute and then change the url using `pushState`. I then am using ajax to take that href and grab all HTML that is within a container div, which in this case is a div with the id of `transition`, and do some fading between the content. So I am replacing HTML on the page with HTML pulled using ajax.

This works perfectly the first time I click an anchor link with the class of `transitionLink`, but once I try to click another anchor link, that was received within the HTML a got from the ajax call, it does not using the ajax function to then grab HTML and replace it, instead it just links like a normal link would.

I assume the issue with this is the content pulled using ajax isn't recognizing the ajax function and that is why it is functioning like a normal link.

My question is what is the best way to layout my function so that the ajax call will still work when clicking an anchor link that was received from an ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding content dynamicly to your page, you need to register the Jquery listener back each time you add content.

```
function registerEvents() {
    $(".transitionLink").on("click", handleTransitionClick);
}

function handleTransitionClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    window.history.pushState(null, null, href);
    $(".transitionLink").removeClass("transitionLink--active");
    $(this).addClass("transitionLink--active");
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#transition").fadeOut(250, function () {
                var newPage = $(data).find('#transition').html();
                $("#transition").html(newPage);
                $("#transition").fadeIn(250);
                // Notice here, we are reruning the registerEvents function so the new elements will be registered aswell.
                registerEvents();
            });
        }
    });

}
// Here we are running the register function once, so the initial listener will be added to the initial elements.
registerEvents();
```